# How to convert video file to Base64 string in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, base64

I want to convert local resource folder video file(12345.mp4) to base64 encoding string and then send into the server side from API but web team telling invalid base64 encoded string. Is this correct?

This is my code :

```
 NSString *base64String = @"";
 NSError *error;
 NSData *videoData;

 NSString *strVideoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"12345" ofType:@"mp4"];

 videoData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:strVideoPath options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:&error];
 base64String = [videoData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

Comment: Do you get a base64 string? It's unclear what you are really asking.

Comment: @rmaddy Yeah I'm getting encrypted base64 string but I'm not sure that is valid base64 string or not

Comment: It's definitely not encrypted. The only way to know if it is valid is to use it. You must have some reason to convert to base64. Keep moving forward and see if your result works.

Comment: @rmaddy can you share me the sample code where I am mistaken?

Comment: Your not mistaken. The code you posted is fine. It creates a base64 string.

Comment: This is almost assuredly not going to work, in the long run.   At the least, you're going to end up consuming A TON of memory doing this.  It is a bit odd to encode a video in such a format to start with, but.. ok... if you are going to do that with videos of any size, you'll really need to use some kind of buffered approach that reads N bytes of video data, encodes it, sends it and then moves on to the next chunk.

Answer (score 3):

In **swift** version you can convert video like this

```
 *let tempURL = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL]
                let data = NSData(contentsOf: tempURL as! URL)
                print("\(String(describing: data?.length))")
              
                if data?.length ?? 0 > 0{
                      guard data != nil else {
                        return
                      }
                      let base64String = data!.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
                    self.video = base64String
                }*
```